# RemoteControlClient wear play/pause does not work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, wear-os

I am registering RemoteControlClient to control playback in my application. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html
it shows playback notification on android wear, but buttons play/pause/next/prev does not work on wear, volume up/down work. It also work locally on phone, so i think remotecontrolclient is registered correctly. Does someone faced up with this problem too? Any advices?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you running the Android 5.0 Developer Preview on your phone?

Comment: no. i am on android 4.3. by the way google play music works on my phone with wear remotecontrolclient music controls. other player i`ve tried do not work too.

Comment: @ianhanniballake do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on Android 4.3, Android Wear only sends specific Intents that are unique to Google Play Music, rather than using the standard functionality to [handle media controls](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls). In Android 4.4, they use [RemoteController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html) to correctly send media events, in place of their custom solution on Android 4.3 (hence, why it works on those devices).

I've filed an issue with the Android Wear team to use the standard functionality, which should eventually fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please share link to issue, so i can check its status?